# Can a vector space have more than one zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The question above is really it. The reason I ask is that my text says a vector space can have more than one zero vector (It's a true/false question: A vector space may have more than one zero vector). But if the zero vector in any space is unique, then it has only one zero vector, no?

Or am I reading "unique" wrong?

Comment: In fact, neutral elements are unique in whatever algebraic structure you work with.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By unique we can say that there is only one zero vector. To see this, Suppose that we have a vector space with two zero vectors, $x,x'$, then we have

$$
x = x+x' = x' + x = x'.
$$

Thus the zero vector is indeed unique.

Comment: Only one minute later, the result is much different.

Comment: @Paul , this is actually my first post, many questions are already answered so well by the time I see them that I saw this with no responses and scrambled to get a decent response in quickly.

Comment: Why? I hate myself that type too slowly. Beat my head;Beat my head;Beat my head;;(:(:( I just get one vote!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks, I realized that I was reading the text wrong -- I thought it said that you COULD have more than one zero vector when in fact it was saying you couldn't.

Answer (score 4):

You're correct. Saying that a vector space has a unique zero vector means it has *exactly* one--no more, no less.

Answer (score 4):

Only one. To see it, let $O_1$ and $O_2$ be two zero vectors, then we have $O_2=O_2+O_1=O_1$.

Comment: Your last equation might be better written as $$O_2=O_2+O_1=O_1$$

Comment: @Peter: Yes. I'm too hurry. However it is late to post. Just one minite later than Kennny.